# Using httpclient in MVC application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, dotnet-httpclient

When I invoke below function in a console app, it just works.  But when I add the same to a MVC controller, execution never reaches JsonConvert line.  Any idea, what I am missing.

Calling code

```
GetVersion(url).Result.FileVersion
```

Method

```
public static async Task<Version> GetVersion(string url, string hostHeader)
{
    var client = new HttpClient();
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(hostHeader))
    {
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Host = hostHeader;
    }
    var version = await client.GetStringAsync(url);
    var output = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Version>(version);
    client.Dispose();
    return output;
}
```

Comment: Which MVC Version are you using?

Comment: MVC4, .net4.5, vs2012

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are causing a deadlock, as I [explain on my blog](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html). By default, `await` captures a "context" (in this case, the ASP.NET request context) and uses that to resume the `async` method. The ASP.NET request context only allows one thread in at a time, and you're blocking that thread by calling `Result`, thus preventing the `async` method from completing.

Your console app doesn't deadlock because it doesn't have a "context", so the `async` methods resume on the thread pool.

The solution is to change the calling code to use:

```
(await GetVersion(url)).FileVersion
```

Comment: Thank you, this works.  I will read your blog in detail to understand more