# How can I successfully use HttpClient to access iTunes search service in MVC4 app

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, async-await, dotnet-httpclient

I am writing an MVC4 app, and in the controller, I need to be able to make a call to a web service to access the iTunes search service in order to get some cover art for a DVD.

I have the following very simple code

```
public static string GetAlbumArt(Movie movie) {
  Task<string> lookupTask = LookupAlbumArt(movie.Title, movie.Year);
  lookupTask.Wait(5000);
  if (lookupTask.IsCompleted)
  {
    return lookupTask.Result;
  }
  else
  {
    return Timeout;
  }
}

private static async Task<string> LookupAlbumArt(string title, int year)
{
  using (var client = new HttpClient())
  {                                
    string response= await client.GetStringAsync(
      "http://itunes.apple.com/search?term=hoosiers&media=movie"
    );                
    return response;                
  }
}
```

When I run this and set breakpoints at the `return Timeout` line in `GetAlbumArt` and also at the `return response` line in `LookupAlbumArt`, the Timeout breakpoint is hit first, and then the `LookupAlbumArt` return statement is hit, and the correct content is in the `response` variable.

If I remove the timeout parameter from `lookupTask.Wait(5000)`, the `wait GetStringAsync` call never returns, and the page never loads.

This feels like a pretty straightforward task, and I'm stumped as to what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: It looks like [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20626541/using-httpclient-in-mvc-application) is probably the same issue.  The question linked from there has way more details.

Comment: Thanks Mark  Somehow I missed that when I was trying to figure out the problem.  Didn't mean to post a duplicate.  I wish http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-clients/calling-a-web-api-from-a-net-client (top hit on Google for ".NET HttpClient example") took this into account!